# Identify SOD882 diode marked F1

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

I am trying to identify a diode on a Turtle Beach controller. I can't find what diode this could be.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several diodes marked F1 from several manufacturers, but this one looks very much like a PESD5V0S1BL315 ESD diode as offered on [AliExpress](https://aliexpress.com/item/1005006209708965.html) and [Alibaba](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Factory-Price-Of-Electronic-components-PESD5V0S1BL315_62380370814.html) (no affiliation, in fact, I avoid buying there), which seems to be a clone of Nexperia's SOD-882 [PESD5V0S1BL](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PESD5V0S1BL.pdf), which, according to the datasheet (table 4 on page 2), also has the marking "F1".

Best guess; no guarantees.

Comment: The question says the diode package is ``SOD-882``, which is _leadless_. From the admittedly fuzzy picture in the question the solder appears to have wicked up the sides of the diodes as if maybe a different leaded package. Do you think the diode package is a SOD-882 or could it actually be a different package?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response. My best guess was a sod 882 as the measurements were nearly bang on with the sod package. Sorry for the picture

Comment: I tried adding more pictures but have to reduce the size which made the images worse. When i look at the diode from side view you can see two pins (which sod882 have) The diode sits across the 5v from input (surface charger)

Comment: As it is close to a pin header this is most likely an ESD protection diode, I approve